# Take snapshot of specific EC2 instance using lambda using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to setup an automated EBS snapshot in AWS using AWS Lambda and Event Rules.
The below Python code is working fine, but it is taking snapshots of every volume of each EC2 instance present in the region.

```
import json
import boto3 
import time
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError 
def lambda_handler(event, context):

try:
    # EC2 Client
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')
    # Get Volume ID of EBS attached to EC2 Instnace
    response = client.describe_volumes()
    if len(response['Volumes']) > 0:
      for k in response['Volumes']:
          print("EBS Volume ID : ",k['VolumeId'], " of EC2 Instance : ", k['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId'])
          try:
              # Create a Snapshot of Volume
              responsesnapsnot = client.create_snapshot(VolumeId= k['VolumeId'])
              print("Snapshot Created with ID : ", responsesnapsnot['SnapshotId'])
          except Exception as e:
              print("some error :", e)
    return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps("sucess")
            }
except ClientError as e:
        print("Detailed error: ",e)
        return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'body': json.dumps("error")
           
                }
except Exception as e:
        print("Detailed error: ",e)
        return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'body': json.dumps("error")
           
                }
```

How I restrict it to the specific instance ID that I am passing in the event pattern?[image]

Comment: Check the `event` to see how the instance ID is being passed to the Lambda function. You can do this by inserting `print(event)` at the top of the handler function. Then, add an `if` statement before creating the snapshot to confirm that the Volume is attached to the desired Instance. You are already printing that info, so the information is available.